# Spread 2 columns (convert from long to wide form) into 4 in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have data in this form

```
id  year    facname class_code       line_no    value
1     1         A        County           1      county1
1     1         A        County           2      county2
1     1         A        source1          1      9
1     1         A        source1          2      4
1     1         A        source2          1      7
1     1         A        source2          2      2
1     1         A        source3          1      8...

2     1         B        County           1      county1
2     1         B        County           2      county1
2     1         B        source1          1      21
2     1         B        source1          2      9
2     1         B        source2          1      4
2     1         B        source2          2      7 ....
```

I am trying to convert this into something like this : 
(note the last 3 columns will have the values 'spread' accordingly)

```
id year facname   line_no        County      source1        source2      source3
1   1    A       1               county1      9                7           8      
1   2    A       2               county2      4                2           NA
1   3    A       3               county3             
1   4    A       4               county4
2   1    B       1               county1
2   2    B       2               county2
2   3    B       3               county3
2   4    B       4               county4
```

This will show the different number of payers (source1,source2, source3) and the county names (county1, county2) that the counties belong to.
I know its some combination of spread (and possibly gather) but I'm unable to put my head around it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!
(PS: I understand this is probably a duplicate question but I'm really new to tidying data)

edit: The counties (county1,2..etc.) are actually numbers (in the original dataset) but are categorical in nature, so I'm calling them as county1, the other values (sources) are actually number of people in that county participating in events (source1, source2 etc.). There are a total of 40 line_no's for each facility.

Comment: What is the logic you think to decide `county`? Its not very clear from data.

Comment: @MKR Basically in this case the counties (county1, county 2, etc.) are numerical county codes (categorical). For simplicity, I used county1, county2 instead of their respective county codes ("01", "20"). While the others are numerical (2 persons in source1, 3 persons in source2, etc.) Since the value column (original dataset) is numeric in nature, I'm unable to form the logic as to how I should use spread. I made a mistake with copying the line numbers initially, I've corrected it now. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Thats fine. But for few rows you have mentioned `county1` and for others you have mentioned a `number`. For consistency, can we not use  `conuty1`, `county2`, `county3` etc. Is that the way your data will be?

Comment: The 'county3', 'county4' are not in the input data

Comment: @MKR yeah, they're all not counties. There are a total of 40 line_numbers for each facname (facility Name) of which there are only some payers (persons in source1, source2 and source3) Instead of displaying all 40, I thought this might be convenient. Sorry I should have added a "..." between facilities A and B to denote that there are a whole lot of line codes and respective sources in between. Will update the thread!

Comment: @AnuragKaushik Yea. I think I had understood logic at end. I hope either of the answer will solve your purpose. You can try these on real data.frame.

Comment: Thank you both! :)
@akrun, sorry there are like 40 counties in there. I've edited my post based on your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to use double `tidyr::spread` as:

**UPDATED:** based on comments from @CJYetman

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Just spread can transform and work on present sample data used by OP
df %>% spread(class_code, value)

#The complicated version below based was initially used to handle different
#line numbers for rows with "County" and rows without "County"
filter(df, class_code == "County") %>% spread(class_code, value) %>% 
left_join(filter(df, class_code != "County") %>% spread(class_code, value),
  by=c("id", "line_no", "facname")) 

#   id facname line_no  County source1 source2 source3
# 1  1       A       1 county1       9       7       8
# 2  1       A       2 county2       4       2    <NA>
# 3  2       B       1 county1      21       4    <NA>
# 4  2       B       2 county1       9       7    <NA>
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"id  facname class_code       line_no    value
1   A        County           1      county1
1   A        County           2      county2
1   A        source1          1      9
1   A        source1          2      4
1   A        source2          1      7
1   A        source2          2      2
1   A        source3          1      8
2   B        County           1      county1
2   B        County           2      county1
2   B        source1          1      21
2   B        source1          2      9
2   B        source2          1      4
2   B        source2          2      7",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting the same error I was getting when I was trying spread (of course, it was nowhere close to as complicated as the one you posted). I love the logic you've used as I'm trying to improve on my tidy and dplyr skills.

This is the error ("Duplicate identifiers for rows") which I don't quite understand what it means. Thanks a lot for helping out, I'll keep playing with this solution after my project is completed. :)

Comment: @CJYetman You are absolutely correct. Actually, initially there were confusion with data and expected output. As you can notice OP stills gets some problem on his actual data.frame. I'll edit answer and put your comment as I can see current solution is confusing others.

Comment: @MKR Thanks a lot! The simple code actually worked. The people who gave me the data missed a crucial component, the 'year of observation'. I admit its totally my fault for not following up with them earlier and checking the accuracy of the data! The basic Solution given by CJ Yetman was what yielded the answer! I didn't have access to data over the weekend so I couldn't update! Thank you everyone!

Comment: I've updated the post accordingly so if anyone arrives at this page doesn't get confused

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), id + facname + rowid(class_code) ~ class_code, value.var = 'value')
#     id facname class_code  County source1 source2 source3
#1:  1       A          1 county1       9       7       8
#2:  1       A          2 county2       4       2      NA
#3:  2       B          3 county1      21       4      NA
#4:  2       B          4 county1       9       7      NA
```

---

If we need the 8 rows as in the expected output

```
dcast(setDT(df1), id + facname + rowid(class_code) ~ class_code, 
    value.var = 'value', drop = FALSE)[ ,.SD[!all(is.na(County))], .(id, facname)]
#   id facname class_code  County source1 source2 source3
#1:  1       A          1 county1       9       7       8
#2:  1       A          2 county2       4       2      NA
#3:  1       A          3      NA      NA      NA      NA
#4:  1       A          4      NA      NA      NA      NA
#5:  2       B          1      NA      NA      NA      NA
#6:  2       B          2      NA      NA      NA      NA
#7:  2       B          3 county1      21       4      NA
#8:  2       B          4 county1       9       7      NA
```

Comment: The first one is almost close to what I want! Instead of class_code, I'd like the line_no to become a column. I'll try to tweak the code, but if you can edit your answer I'll be very grateful :D! Thanks so much!

Comment: @AnuragKaushik  That will be easy to do it. `setDT(df1)[, line_no: rowid(class_code); dcast(df1, id + facname + line_no ~ class_code, ...`